# Why we called a measurement as a Bell measurement?

Tags: bell-basis

So I am new to quantum computing, just come along the topic of Bell's measurement, until now we understood that we apply the Bell inverse (transpose conjugate) before taking measurement, so Bell's inverse will act as change of basis from Bell's basis |Φ+⟩, |Ψ+⟩, |Φ-⟩, |Ψ-⟩ into the computational basis states |00⟩, |01⟩, |10⟩, |11⟩, respectively, and then we take measurement in $z$-basis only so why we called it as measuring along Bell's basis ? Is it correct to say "we are taking measurement along Bell's basis |Φ+⟩, |Ψ+⟩, |Φ-⟩, |Ψ-⟩" ?, I would love if you answer me from a linear algebraic perspective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and then we take measurement in z-basis only so why we called it as measuring along bell-basis

The change of basis maps each Bell state uniquely to one of
$$\{|00\rangle, |01\rangle, |10\rangle |11\rangle \}$$

Therefore measuring in the Z-basis after the change of basis is equivalent to measuring in the Bell basis before the change of basis.

> like is it correct to say "we are taking measurement along bell-basis |Φ+⟩, |Ψ+⟩, |Φ-⟩, |Ψ-⟩" ?

Yes, this is correct.